# Solving for x in equations with logarithms

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

I have a function that we use for some game calculations, but now I need to reverse it and solve for `x`. I have no idea how to do that. The function looks like this:

$$y = 10 + \frac{ ( {ln(x)} ^ {ln(x)} ) ^ {1.2} }{3}$$

I get about as far as this:

$$(3y - 30)^\frac{1}{1.2} = {ln(x)} ^ {ln(x)}$$

And then I'm stumped. How can I solve for `x` in this scenario?

Comment: Is it $\ln(x^{\ln x})$  or $(\ln x)^{\ln x} $

Comment: It's the natural log of x, raised to the power of the natural log of x, raise to the power of 1.2.

Here's (more or less) the raw code we use: `10 + ( ( log(x)**log(x) )**1.2 ) / 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse function of $f(x) = x^x$ is $$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{\ln x}{W (\ln x)},$$  where $W$ is the Lambert omega function.  This inverse is good only for $x>1/e.$

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.)

So in your equation, you can solve for $\ln x$:

$$\ln x = \frac{\ln( (3y-30)^{1/1.2} )}{W (\ln( (3y-30)^{1/1.2} ))} =
      \frac{(5/6)\ln( (3y-30) )}{W ((5/6)\ln( (3y-30))}.$$

So $x = e$ raised to that mess.

If this is for some computational purpose, there are series approximations for $W$.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. I actually have a constraint where I know x is an integer between 1 and 50, inclusive, so my first pass at solving this was actually a binary search. I was just hoping for something a touch more elegant than my brute force approach, but now it seems my brute force may be easier for developers (though I'll link to this so they can see alternatives).

Comment: If $x$ can take on only $50$ values, one could easily have a computer algebra system solve the equation numerically for each value and create a table of values to whatever precision one wanted.  Then the application would only have to look up the values, rather than compute them on the fly.